# MySQL - NOT IN (.... a gazillion items ... ), will it scale?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm going to be trying to access records, but will exclude records with, say, a list of ids using a syntax like this:

`WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,6,7, ...`

As my database gets bigger, that list of ids will also get bigger. Am I going to have a problem someday?

Comment: That's probably a good indication that you need to improve your database design. There has to be a better way to flag those records.

Comment: yes. try to something like an boolean called "visible" and use WHERE `visible` = 0

Comment: How many records are we talkingn about? 10^2, 10^5, 10^100?

Comment: a googol. Well played RedX. ye, you might want to redesign your database/ include a bit column to your table for each row to mark it as excluded or not

Comment: JohnConde, Bondye, EonRustedduPlessis - it's not as simple as setting a flag. There are actually a number of queries I'll have to do to determine which records to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider storing the list of ids to exclude in a different table, then use the following SQL:

```
WHERE id NOT IN (select id from excluded_ids);
```

Put an index on the `id` column of `excluded_ids` for scalabilty.

Comment: Not that simple. Assume something like a social network. You want to exclude the profiles whose privacy setting is set to "private." Then you also want to exclude the profiles who have blocked a particular user (so that the user can't see those profiles that have blocked him). And then you want to exclude those profiles that have not been active in the last 3 months. And then ... I don't think a different table is feasible.

Comment: Also, what if `excluded_ids` has a gazillion records? How is this better than providing a comma separated list?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, if you use the table with an index, MySQL won't have to sort the comma separated list. MySQL performs a binary search against the constants inside the `IN()` clause, but in order to do this, it first sorts the values. `IN` scales, but only as much as a binary search scales.

Comment: Does it have to be a separate table containing all the ids I need to exclude? Or can I just nest the query? `WHERE id NOT IN (...crazy SQL here...`

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: To answer your second comment, if `excluded_ids` has a gazillion records, then you probably couldn't get away with embedding them in your query as a comma separated list anyway -- you'd hit MySQL parser limits. (It sounds like you'd have to get all of that data to your client, build the list on your client, then send it back to the server anyway, which is inefficient and inelegant). To answer your fourth comment, if you're determining what ids to exclude using a query, you can just embed that query in your SQL statement -- no need for an intermediate table.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the needs of your statement I generally tend to avoid long lists of values in such situations, it shouts for a separate table and a subselect.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the
>   max_allowed_packet value.

Therefore check out the [max_allow_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value in order to make sure your statement doesn't break once this list gets very large.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test on my own database - it has about 8 million rows and I excluded about ten of them. It took 25 seconds to run. I think that means it's not scaleable ;)

Comment: I would say that this is not an answer but a comment :)