# Alternative methods to do SQL query with a long long IN conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `User`.*
FROM    `user` AS `Users`
WHERE   `Users`.`group_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10........)
```

My problem is that the IN conditions could be very very long 
I would ask if anyone has some ideas about alternative methods to do this without this problem  ?
My SHOW CREATE TABLE users is

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  password char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  first_name varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  group_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on why you need to do it a different way? Are you hand typing these? What's the context of the query? Where do the group ids that you are using the IN operator on come from?

Comment: how you are getting comma seperated list?

Comment: Because I think that in the long run I will go over the limit of max size of query.


I get  the group ids from other queries and they are in a php array

Comment: Sounds like *failed by design*, because a `group_id` shouldn't handle that mutch groups. Maybe normalize the groups to something like *groups of groups* and take them to a higher level?

Comment: The normalization is correct . A user belongs to a group . I have would find all users of some groups (many groups)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - NOT IN (.... a gazillion items ... ), will it scale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602611/mysql-not-in-a-gazillion-items-will-it-scale)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing values between queries through `PHP`, just do it in MySQL itself (using `JOIN`):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `Users`.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    your_query
        ) q
JOIN    `user` AS `Users`
ON      `Users`.group_id = q.id
```

Create an index on `user.group_id`

Comment: @MarcoRizzetto: how many records does the innermost query return?

Comment: there are two thousands records approx.

Comment: For how long does it run? For how long do your original queries run?

Comment: it lasts 130ms , all queries togheter 52 ms

Comment: Could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE user`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: @MarcoRizzetto: please move it to your original post, it's unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've created *processing tables* for tasks like this that I would truncate and then fill with the data I needed to use for the subsequent query. This was done mainly in non-real time situations where I was moving data from one set of tables to another for reporting.

Basically I'd do something like:

```
# clear out the staging table (or maybe create a temporary table if that makes sense for you)
truncate staging_table

# go fetch all the group_id's needed into this staging table
INSERT INTO staging_table table
SELECT  distinct group_id
FROM ... 

# Now get all the users like so:
SELECT  DISTINCT `User`.*
FROM    `user` AS `Users` 
  JOIN staging_table on `Users`.`group_id` = staging_table.group_id;
```

The *IN LIST* is now gone because basically all the group_id's you want are in a table.

It's possible this may be slower since you're breaking this into 2 queries instead of one. However, in my case some of the 'in lists' I'd have had were literally 10's of thousands long and MySQL (at least at the time) would choke on them.

A couple notes:

- If this is something where multiple users can be doing this simultaneously, you'll probably need to use TEMPORARY TABLES to separate the users.
- There were times when I got good milage out of adding indexes to the working tables when I added multiple columns to them.